# How to put a borrowdate into my calculation fines

Tags: php

I want to input a `$borrowdate` into the code because I think that's why my penalties is continuously updating a code even if it's returned. This is the table [image: August 27]  The date is August 27 and the penalties continuously going on.

```
$borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_return']); // This code


$returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date']);
$currentdate = new Datetime();

$returndate->setTime(0,0);
$currentdate->setTime(0,0);

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($returndate, $interval, $currentdate);

$weekendDays = 0;
$totalDays = 0;

foreach ( $period as $p ) {
$totalDays++;



if($p->format( "w" )==0) $weekendDays++;
}

echo "<p>Total  days: $totalDays</p><p>Weekend days: $weekendDays </p>";
$fines = ($totalDays - $weekendDays) * 15;
echo "₱ ". $fines;
$fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a setTime for Borrowdate and I replace the `$currentdate`
 in

`$period = new DatePeriod($returndate, $interval, $currentdate);`

**INTO**

`$period = new DatePeriod($returndate, $interval, $borrowdate);`

```
$borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_return']);
$returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date']);
$currentdate = new Datetime();

$returndate->setTime(0,0);
$currentdate->setTime(0,0);
$borrowdate->setTime(0,0);

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($returndate, $interval, $borrowdate);

$weekendDays = 0;
$totalDays = 0;

foreach ( $period as $p ) {
$totalDays++;
if($p->format( "w" )==0) $weekendDays++;
}

echo "<p>Total  days: $totalDays</p><p>Weekend days: $weekendDays </p>";
$fines = ($totalDays - $weekendDays) * 15;
echo "₱ ". $fines;
$fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
```